# Keras : Create MobileNet_V2 model "AttributeError"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have successfully built several model based on mobileNet using keras. I noticed that MobileNet_V2 as been added in Keras 2.2.0, but I could not manage to make it work :

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import mobilenet_v2

base_model = mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

I get the following error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'` on this line from mobilenet_v2.py `data_format=backend.image_data_format()`

It seems to me that `backend`has a definition problem... I am using Tensorflow backend, maybe it does not work with this one ?

Comment: what does keras.backend.image_data_format() return if you run it in a terminal? (After importing Keras).

Comment: it returns `channels_last`

Comment: Then you should provide an example that reproduces this problem, do you by any chance defined a variable called backend?

Comment: the two lines I have provided are sufficient to reproduce the problem. during the second line the backend variable seems to be reset : `backend = None` at the beginning of mobilenet_v2.py...

Comment: Ok true, this fails in Keras 2.2.4, I would open an issue in github as it seems its a bug in Keras itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is from the import. The proper way to do this is to do the following :

```
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
m = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

Comment: of course because as said in the question it is only available since 2.2.0